# Upgrade from angular 13 to 14 - routing problem

Tags: angular

After update to version 14 i'm getting this error:

**Invalid configuration of route 'map/operator/': a componentless route without children or loadChildren cannot have a named outlet set**

This is my router config:

```
path: 'operator', component: HomeViewComponent, children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'list/', outlet: 'alarms', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'list/:key', component: AlarmsListComponent, outlet: 'alarms' },
  { path: 'details/:keyType/:keyValue', component: AlarmDetailsComponent, outlet: 'alarms' }
]
```

}

How can it be fixed?

Comment: it's clear but if i remove the outlet prop it's not working. I need that AlarmsListComponent component will be the default for path: ''

Comment: You don’t seem to have a route for the path it is redirecting to in the first place (list/)

Comment: i tried this but it's not working
    path: 'operator', component: HomeViewComponent, children: [
      { path: '', redirectTo: 'list/', pathMatch: 'full' },
      { path: 'list/', component: AlarmsListComponent, outlet: 'alarms' },
      { path: 'list/:key', component: AlarmsListComponent, outlet: 'alarms' },
      { path: 'details/:keyType/:keyValue', component: AlarmDetailsComponent, outlet: 'alarms' }
    ]

Answer (score 0):

I think you should use it as below:

```
    const routes: Routes = [
  {path: 'operator', component: HomeViewComponent,
    outlet: 'alarms',
    children: [
  { path: '', redirectTo: 'list/', pathMatch: 'full' },
  { path: 'list/:key', component: AlarmsListComponent },
  { path: 'details/:keyType/:keyValue', component: AlarmDetailsComponent }
]}
];
```

Comment: I tried this but im getting:
Cannot read properties of null (reading 'snapshot'). Also i deleted those line that try to get title and still not working at all and no error message